# Optimize WebView for HTML5 games

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I'm trying to load HTML5 games in an Android WebView. I just wanted to get an idea of what some of the best settings would be for the WebView. Also, on occasion, some of the games won't always load properly when I start the activity, causing me to have to restart the activity (sometimes multiple times until it works). However, if I put the app in the background and come back to it, the game seems to load perfectly every time. Lastly, should I be creating a "local web server" for these games? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Please first of all, tell me if you are testing the app, on an emulator or a real device?
If it is an emulator, then i strongly recommend you to test it on a real device!

Or if you are testing on a real device, then please check if you have enabled javascript using the following code:

```
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I'm testing using real devices, and I do indeed have JavaScript set to enabled :)